# How to change UITableView cellrows on state change of UISwitch in Navigationbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having two methods in my `UITableViewController` class.

```
[self itemProcessor]; //First Method
[self listAllItems];  //Second Method
```

First method will get called by default from my `viewDidLoad` and the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets populated based on the query from my first method. I have a Programmatically created `UISwitch` in my `viewDidLoad` like the below

```
UISwitch *barSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:barSwitch];
    [barSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(setState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; //To track switch state.

- (void)setState:(id)sender
{
    BOOL state = [sender isOn];
    NSString *rez = state == YES ? @"YES" : @"NO";
    NSLog(@"state is %@",rez);

}
```

I should call secondMethod(`[self listAllItems];`) when the switch is off. I have all my arrays getting initialized in my `viewDidLoad`. How do i call two different queries based on the state change when i create the switch programmatically inside `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a NSMutableArray , which you will use in viewDidLoad first, then update that array inside setState function and call tableView.reloadData()

```
- (void)setState:(id)sender
{
    BOOL state = [sender isOn];
    NSString *rez = state == YES ? @"YES" : @"NO";
    NSLog(@"state is %@",rez);

    if (state == YES) {
        // 
    }else{
        // myArray is declared in the .h file 
        myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"str1", @"str2",
                          @"etc", nil];
        [self.tableView reloadData]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: My [self.tableView reloadData] inside setState is not loading i think it's bcoz I already did [self.tableView reloadData]; while executing my query.

Comment: is that line getting called? put a print statement right above it to check it gets there? Is there anything on the tableView after you change the switch? reloadData can be called any amount of times

Comment: Thanks Jaimy for your answer. I've a break point in my ViewDidLoad... My reloadData inside setState is not invoking the viewDidLoad :(

Comment: the viewDidLoad is only invoked once when the app starts.  Is any print statement in setState printing ?

Comment: Yes setState is getting called on changing my switch. But when the reloadData happens i want to call my second method as my second query is in that method. All my array initializations are inside my viewDidLoad(). I am really confused on how to achieve this.

Comment: you have to initialize the arrays again in either setState or a function called from setState in a line above the [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: Jaimy I already tried and since i don't have 15 reputation i couldn't up-vote :(

Comment: I upvoted your question it was concise and clear. Now you can upvote too! :)